# Run tasks simultaneously in React Native

Tags: reactjs, multithreading, react-native, expo

I have a React Native app which is built using Expo, I currently have a single axios call to a serverless function which returns a specific status.

I understand that JS is not multi-threaded so what are my options when it comes to running multiple axios calls concurrently and handling each response separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all()` to execute multiple API calls in parallel

For more info visit link below,

https://javascript.info/promise-api